# Defining constant in a plugin to use in another plugin

Tags: plugins, php, variables

I am wondering if this is possible or if there is another, better way, of doing things. Google-foo didn't help.

So, I have two plugins, aa-frontend and aa-site. I need to define a constant or variable in aa-site/plugin.php and use it in aa-frontend/folder/somefile.php.

Tried with:

```
function site_wp_features(){
    define('AA_PLUGIN_GUTENBERG', false);
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'site_wp_features', 0)
```

But I get:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant AA_PLUGIN_GUTENBERG
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you need this constant for, and what problem you're attempting to solve? I get the feeling that a constant in one of the plugins isn't the best option.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have a plugin that has some frontend functions that we use on almost all sites: aa-frontend, and that plugin needs to be updateable, and we have a aa-site plugin that has functions for that site only, and would need to enable or disable functions from aa-frontend. I am using that const for that.

Comment: @JacobPeattie for example:
pp-site: AA-FUNCTION = true
pp-frontend: if AA-FUNCTION == true REQUIRE_ONCE file.php

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a constant, define the variable as an option stored in the wp_options table so that it can be accessed from any plugin.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit and explain why do you suggest that option stored in DB is an alternative for constant defined in PHP?

Comment: use `add_option()`, `update_option()` and `get_option()` and I suggest it because it is works and is a good solution.  I . have seen plenty of plugins that declare static variables to achieve the same effect as making an option in the database, but I personally prefer the database route, esp. for fetched data because you can store that in a transient and only fetch it sometimes which would reduce load times.